# RestSharp - How to avoid serialization of hidden class members?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm hiding an inherited member `bool` to allow its value as `null` (I have to).
But when I use the instance of this class in the serialization the original value is serialized and not the `bool?`.

```
  public class SomeDto
 {
    public  bool IsRemoved { get; set; } = false; //Serialization is using this one
 }

  public class SomeClass: SomeDto 
 {
    public  new bool? IsRemoved { get; set; }//Instead of this one
 }


  private void Serialize()
 {
   SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
   someClass.IsRemoved = null;

   RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
   request.AddBody(someClass);
 }
```

Is there anyway to force the serialization to get this new property instead of the original one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your types are not the same. declaring 'new' on that is useless as it will not override it just because of the name, both types will exist on the object (you will have a nullable bool, and a regular bool [which is the same as anything, you could declare it as a string, etc, you're not actually hiding it from the compiler]).

The only way I could suggest to fix this is to import JSON.Net, set RestSharps jsonserializer to use [JSON.Nets RestSharp Serializer](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/86b31f9adf049d7fb821de8279154f41a17b36f7/RestSharp/Serializers/JsonSerializer.cs) and adding it to not parse the base objects type (unless you needit under other cases to serialize the base type, but if that's the case you need to redo your strategy on this)